# How can I enable zswap?

Tags: kernel, performance, swap

Ubuntu 13.10's [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes#Linux_kernel_3.11) mention that it includes Linux 3.11, which [supports something called zswap](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.11#head-e34ed8623c5b96a292064848451d3a7f85faa449):

> Zswap is a lightweight, write-behind compressed cache for swap pages. It takes pages that are in the process of being swapped out and attempts to compress them into a dynamically allocated RAM-based memory pool. If this process is successful, the writeback to the swap device is deferred and, in many cases, avoided completely. This results in a significant I/O reduction and performance gains for systems that are swapping

That sounds cool. How can I try it out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note: Some releases of the kernel aren't capable of using zswap. See bug [#1315203](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1315203).

According to the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/zswap.txt), zswap can be enabled by setting `zswap.enabled=1` at boot time. Zswap is is still an experimental technology,

> NOTE: Zswap is a new feature as of v3.11 and interacts heavily with memory
>   reclaim.  This interaction has not be fully explored on the large set of
>   potential configurations and workloads that exist.  For this reason, zswap
>   is a work in progress and should be considered experimental.

so it would be wise to only enable it temporarily at first:

1. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> at boot to enter GRUB's menu.
2. Edit the commands for `Ubuntu` to include `zswap.enabled=1` at the end of the `linux` line.
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

If you want to enable zswap permanently, [edit the GRUB configuration file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-default.2BAC8-grub) to include `zswap.enabled=1` at the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry.

Comment: kernel 3.13.0-79-generic supports zswap

Comment: I get this error when trying your proposal in Ubuntu 16.04 http://askubuntu.com/q/802759/25388

Comment: Also relevant here is to [verify that zwap is active and to see what it does](https://askubuntu.com/q/510516).

Answer (score 2):

Kernel 3.13.0-24-generic does not support zswap:

```
$ cat /boot/config-3.13.0-24-generic | grep ZSWAP
#CONFIG_ZSWAP is not set
```

Comment: `cat /boot/config-3.13.0-36-generic | grep ZSWAP
CONFIG_ZSWAP=y`  I don't know if that was a mistake or not but my Ubuntu 14.04 system does support ZSWAP.

Comment: @JordonBedwell It has been enabled and disabled at various times throughout release cycles.