# How to verify zswap running?

Tags: kernel

How can I check to verify that zswap is enabled and working on my system?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
sudo dmesg | grep zswap
```

That should be all you need to know if it's running. You should see a message along the lines of:

```
[    1.241302] zswap: loading zswap
[    1.241306] zswap: using zbud pool
[    1.241310] zswap: using lzo compressor
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 and later, the `dmesg` output is even shorter, like this:

```
[    1.802721] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
```

You can see what it's doing with the following:

```
$ sudo grep -R . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/stored_pages:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_total_size:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/duplicate_entry:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/written_back_pages:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_compress_poor:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_kmemcache_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_alloc_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/reject_reclaim_fail:0
/sys/kernel/debug/zswap/pool_limit_hit:0
```

The key parameters to look out for are `stored_pages` which is the number of compressed pages and `written_back_pages` which is the number of pages which have been written out to the swap file.

Comment: `dmesg | grep zswap` shows nothing on my system (Ubuntu 18.04), but `sudo grep -r . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap` shows zswap is working.

Comment: @scoobydoo Same as you. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @吴毅凡 not sure but now with Ubuntu 20.04 `dmesg | grep zswap` does show that zswap is loaded: `[    1.802721] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud`

Comment: I am looking at this data, but still not sure what it means: What is `stored_pages`, `written_back_pages`, `pool_total_size`?

Comment: Hello! It looks like someone copied your answer, along with the question, to another site without giving attribution. It's at https://ubuntuusa.com/questions/23672/173/How-to-verify-zswap-running , in case you want to contact them. I tried contacting SE, but they said they don't do anything in cases like this anymore.

Comment:  This won't work if zswap has been modified at runtime. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Shell expansion is a weird thing sometimes. `grep` fortunately have a recursive option so to simplify it:

```
sudo grep -r . /sys/kernel/debug/zswap
```

Comment:  This won't work if zswap has been modified at runtime. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are **wrong** if zswap has been modified at runtime.

For checking under any circumstance:

```
cat /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled
```